# componentdidmount does not empty the input field but only after page refresh it gets removed

Tags: reactjs

The input field works fine, but after emptying the field, this value appears again when I visit the page next time.

```
I'm using the componentDidMount which setState for the props of this input value.




  state = {
        rent:null
        }

        componentDidMount(){
         if(this.props.house.rent){
           this.setState({rent:this.props.house.rent});
        }
        }
        onChange = (value) => {
...
this.setState({
value
});
}
        render(){
        <input
        type = "text"
        value={this.state.rent}
...
onChange = {e = > 
                    this.onChange(e.target.value);
             }
        }
```

The expected value is after I empty the input value, It should not appear the next time I visit the page, but it appears again, and gets removed only after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to make this a controlled form. It needs an onChange.

    state = {
      rent: ""
      }

      componentDidMount(){
       if(this.props.house.rent){
         this.setState({rent:this.props.house.rent});
      }
      }

      handleChange = e => {
          this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
          });
        }


      render(){
  return(
      <input
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      type = "text"
      name="rent"
      value={this.state.rent}
      })
```

Comment: Hi thanks, actually forgot to mention in my code, It is indeed a controlled form, but the value appears even after emptying it but gets removed only after refreshing the page.